# "If/as/when necessary"

Tags: differences, conjunctions

Is there any difference between the following sentences?

> 1. Please press the bell if necessary.
> 2. Please press the bell as necessary.
> 3. Please press the bell when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can review use of *if necessary, as necessary,* and *when necessary* via examples drawn from links at [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+necessary%2Cas+necessary%2Cwhen+necessary&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3).  Some sets of examples are given below, with a summary after each set.

> So check all cylinder fins periodically and clean them if necessary. - [Townsend](http://books.google.com/books?id=4M4DAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA130&dq=%22if+necessary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6GAxT9W0Fqb3mAXl673KBQ&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22if%20necessary%22&f=false)
>   ...be willing to see several therapists if necessary in order to find one who is right for you - [Norwood](http://books.google.com/books?id=M9U_uT6CS-kC&pg=PT166&dq=%22if+necessary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6GAxT9W0Fqb3mAXl673KBQ&ved=0CIkBEOgBMBE#v=onepage&q=%22if%20necessary%22&f=false)
>   Then take your complaint to the bully's parents and school authorities, and to the police if necessary. - [L.H.D.](http://books.google.com/books?id=WmEEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA98&dq=%22if+necessary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6GAxT9W0Fqb3mAXl673KBQ&ved=0CJMBEOgBMBM#v=onepage&q=%22if%20necessary%22&f=false)

The above are typical [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if%20necessary%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1923,cd_max:1987&lr=lang_en) of use of *if necessary* in explaining what action to take if certain conditions arise.  It is supposed that the action might or might not be needed, depending on conditions.  While *as necessary* could be used in these examples without particular change in their meanings, such use happens to be rare.

> Repair or replace timer as necessary - [Powell](http://books.google.com/books?id=mzWswaAaeEAC&pg=PA103&dq=%22as+necessary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=u2ExT8WOCMrvmAXkgdXMBQ&ved=0CHUQ6AEwCg#v=onepage&q=%22as%20necessary%22&f=false)
>   Lubricate or replace heat valve as necessary. - [Motor](http://books.google.com/books?id=XA2cHzaYWFMC&q=%22as+necessary%22&dq=%22as+necessary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=u2ExT8WOCMrvmAXkgdXMBQ&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBQ)

These two examples illustrate use of *as necessary* in cases where neither of *if necessary* or *when necessary* are quite right; specifically, where multiple actions may or may not be done, each dependent on conditions.  Note that among numerous surveyed [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20necessary%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1897,cd_max:1987&lr=lang_en) for *as necessary*, it is far more frequently used in a way not of interest here, in sentences like "skilled employees ... should be regarded as necessary employees" ([Railway news](http://books.google.com/books?id=nI7mAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA331&dq=%22as+necessary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=u2ExT8WOCMrvmAXkgdXMBQ&ved=0CH8Q6AEwDA#v=onepage&q=%22as%20necessary%22&f=false)).

> When necessary, the investigator may engage an appropriate specialist - [RSFSR codes](http://books.google.com/books?id=Nx0gnXpMbnsC&pg=PA260&dq=%22when+necessary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=W2ExT8SoD5DomAXKk73DBQ&ved=0CGUQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22when%20necessary%22&f=false)
>   The rope is held in the hands to give the critter slack to play on and is dallied around the saddle-horn when necessary to stop the animal when he goes wrong. - [Ward](http://books.google.com/books?id=FUz1xhAZcKQC&pg=PA96&dq=%22when+necessary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=W2ExT8SoD5DomAXKk73DBQ&ved=0CH4Q6AEwDg#v=onepage&q=%22when%20necessary%22&f=false)
>   ...consideration and approval by the relevant bodies as and when necessary. - [Kenya Gazette](http://books.google.com/books?id=fWeiVJ10IysC&pg=PA870&dq=%22when+necessary%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=W2ExT8SoD5DomAXKk73DBQ&ved=0CHAQ6AEwCw#v=onepage&q=%22when%20necessary%22&f=false)

In these and other [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22when%20necessary%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1923,cd_max:1988&lr=lang_en), use of *when necessary* may be prompted by a sense that conditions *will* arise to make an action necessary; except that in the Kenya Gazette example, *as and when necessary* is, more or less, a verbose set phrase that could be adequately replaced by any of the simpler *if, as* or *when* phrases.

Comment: I would go so far as to say outright that "if" should be used in cases where the condition is possible, but will only occur once; "when" should be used if the condition is likely, but again will only occur once; and "as" should be used if and only if the condition is likely to *reoccur*.

Answer (score 2):

All three read roughly the same to me but if I were to divide them I would do along a spectrum of how often it may be necessary to press the bell. 3 implies (very weakly) pressing once, otherwise whenever would be there in formal language. 2 Implies several presses to my mind. 1 Seems very neutral. Alas I have no source or proof for these gut reactions so don't base any importance on my musings!

Comment: I'll buy that. I think as well as your assessment of *how many times* the bell may need to be pressed, there's also the a strong possibility in (1) and a weak possibility in (2) that the bell may not even need to be pressed at all, let alone multiple times.